# xsl:include href Include Path Dynamically XSLT2.O FOP-2.8

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Inside main xslt, for all other xslt files, that we might need to include, can have different paths and those path can be processed at run time; so that is why I was trying below approch

1. have a xsl:param , will send the parameter with fop options and same will be captured inside this param.
2. Pass this to href of xsl:include;

fop command:
`fop -xml /path/to/xml/file.xml -xsl /path/to/xsl/file.xslt -pdf path/to/output/file.pdf -param IncludePath path/to/include`

Code snap that I am trying:

```
<xsl:param name="IncludePath"></xsl:param>

<xsl:include href ="$IncludePath/testInclude.xslt"/>
```

This is not working; so what will be the possible solution to include the path+file in xsl:include href at run time.

***Update***

Name space check for xslt 3.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
           xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
           xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
           xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"
           xmlns:pre="xalan://org.apache.xalan.Version"
           xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

---

***Update***

---

I am simply trying to create a repository of .xslt file(s), consists of reusable templates and then include them. So that I can orchestrate the same templates by calling them from different standard style sheet.
And yes I don't want to use xsl:import as no need of override the templates in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The `xsl:include` declaration serves to assemble the source code of a stylesheet as the first stage of compilation; by definition, therefore, it cannot be done at run-time.

We need to stand back here and ask what problem you are actually trying to solve. You haven't actually told us, you've only told us about an attempted solution that doesn't work.

One mistake that people are sometimes making when they try something like this is to have the includes/imports "upside down". If you have two variants of a module that you want to use conditionally, say greek.xsl and latin.xsl, then the correct solution is not to try and import one of these conditionally, but rather to have the special-purpose module import (and override) the standard invariant code, and then use the special-purpose module as your main entry point.

With 3.0 another option is to use fn:transform() to invoke a subsidiary stylesheet dynamically.

But please describe your problem, so we have some chance of helping you solve it.

Comment: I had updated what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: You've still described your attempted solution, not your problem.

Comment: My  standard style sheet is becoming more complex and lengthy with increasing need of representing elements using templets so I want to make  our standard style sheet simple and less complex; which probably also going to be helpful for maintenance as well....hope now I am able to explain my problem statement here.

Comment: No, you've only talked about your code, you've said nothing about the problem that the code is designed to solve. We need a design change here and to advise on the design, we need information about the requirements.

Comment: I think I mentioned that the problem is in terms of complexity with my xslt that I want to reduce. And when I am saying complexity that means , length of my standard style sheet is getting increased and more number of template calling is getting involved. So my standard style sheet is becoming a tightly couple solution.

Comment: As I say, it needs redesigning and we can't help you do that without knowing what it's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of XSLT is XSLT 3; in that version one of the new features are static parameters and shadow attributes that allow e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:param name="IncludePath" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="''"/>

<xsl:include _href="{$IncludePath}testInclude.xslt"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that static parameters have to set before compiling the stylesheet; I don't know whether or how easy it is to integrate that into FOP and (the probably used) JAXP API.

Comment: so are we saying that there is no solution in xslt2.0 for the same?

Comment: You might have even ore restricted options in XSLT 2 using `use-when` on different `xsl:import`s but if you expect XSLT 1 or 2 to allow you to dynamically set an import or include href, no, that is not part of the language.

Comment: If we change the version is there a possibility of compatibility issue with the other name space definition that I am using currently?  Add the sample namespace in case we are updating the xslt version with 3.0; so will it work? Update my question as well with namespace

Comment: XSLT 3 is compatible with XSLT 2, I don't think there is XSLT 2 code that doesn't run with an XSLT 3 processor (there might be edge cases where behaviour differs in terms of errors) and while some features in XSLT 3 require the use of additional namespaces there is certainly no way your use of namespaces in XSLT 2 code somehow breaks if you move to an XSLT 3 processor. I think, in terms of the FOP tool chain, the main question, to use static params and shadow attributes, is whether the FOP tool chain provides some way to set static parameters as this has to be done before compilation.

Comment: -param option is there to add any parameter while invoking ; like I added in fop command. But is that what are we looking for? Or we are looking for the information like even if we update the version and syntax my fop will be able to process that or not..is that the question ?

Comment: I think the `fop` command is a shell or bat file that then inside calls a Java command line program that under the hood instantiates a JAXP Transformer to do XSLT if necessary. But the JAXP Transformer API is kind of written for XSLT 1.0 tasks so I am not sure whether it allows any way to set XSLT 3.0 static parameters before compiling the stylesheet. In the end, you might need to decouple the XSLT and FO processing step and run the XSLT step through Saxon's own command line tool before running fop on the result of the transformation.

Comment: yes that is correct we need run exec command to invoke fop; so what i understood we can only leverage the xsl:include and need to keep all the .xslt file in same location.

Comment: It depends on lots of factors; in the end XSLT 3 with the shown static parameters and shadow attributes gives you one option; as Mike has said, `fn:transform` is a second, as might be XSLT 3.0 packages; but all that adds some complexity the default FOP tool chain might not directly handle, so you would need to consider having your own fop runner adaption.